# How to setup a data structure to bind a dynamic list of objects to a treeview in WPF and C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures, data-binding, treeview

Thanks for looking at this!

CreateFoos() method is bound as the data source in WPF for a treeview. Is there a way to rework this so the lists in the constructor can be bound to CreateFoos()?

I have no idea how to rework the data structure to these lists that are populated dynamically.

```
public class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data

        bool? _isChecked = false;
        FooViewModel _parent;

        List<object> Family;
        List<object> child;

        #endregion // Data

        public FooViewModel(List<object> A, List<object> B)
        {
            Family = A;
            child = B;
        }

        #region CreateFoos

        public List<FooViewModel> CreateFoos()
        {
            FooViewModel root = new FooViewModel("Top Wrapper")
            {
                IsInitiallySelected = true,
                Children =
                {
                    new FooViewModel("Family1")
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new FooViewModel("Bob"),
                            new FooViewModel("Jose"),
                            new FooViewModel("Milly"),
                        }
                    },
                    new FooViewModel("Family2")
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new FooViewModel("Susan"),
                            new FooViewModel("Pepper"),
                            new FooViewModel("Gunther"),                            
                        }
                    },
                    new FooViewModel("Family3")
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new FooViewModel("Kim"),
                            new FooViewModel("Beretta"),
                            new FooViewModel("Pedro"),
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

            root.Initialize();
            return new List<FooViewModel> { root };
        }

        FooViewModel(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Children = new List<FooViewModel>();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (FooViewModel child in this.Children)
            {
                child._parent = this;
                child.Initialize();
            }
        }

        #endregion // CreateFoos

        #region Properties

        public List<FooViewModel> Children { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInitiallySelected { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
```

How can the hard-coded FooViewModel data structure get replaced with the dynamic lists in the constructor?

Comment: What are the collections Family and child (or A and B) about? How are they related? Are they?

Comment: Why are they `List<object>` instead of `List<FooViewModel>`

Comment: If you implement inotifypropertychanged and raise propertychanged in the setters then you could add a list of children and the ui will respond. If you made them observablecollections then you could add a child dynamically and the ui will respond. Is that what you're asking?